# How to properly fetch datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms

In my WinForms app, i've three tabs and in each tab a gatagridview.
If i click a btn to display records in tab1 datagridview, it populates **BUT** if i go to tab2 and hit a button to display a different record, it first displays me the right records and then dispalys me the same records in tab1 or tab3 if a different button is clicked.

It then populate me the same record from tab1,tab2 and tab3.

How can i solve this problem  OR is it that i declared a globale Datatable dt variable?

Comment: We need to see the relevant parts of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the 3 `DGVs` to have each his own record pointer you must not use the `DataTable` as their `DataSource` directly. Instead use an intermediate `BindingSource` for each of them:

```
    // assume a few DataGridViews..: 
    DataGridView DGV1 = new DataGridView();
    DataGridView DGV2 = new DataGridView();
    DataGridView DGV3 = new DataGridView();

    // and a common DataTable:
    DataTable DT = new DataTable();
    //..

    // we need a separate BindingSource for each DGV:
    BindingSource BS1 = new BindingSource();
    BindingSource BS2 = new BindingSource();
    BindingSource BS3 = new BindingSource();

    // each is bound to the DataTable
    BS1.DataSource = DT;
    BS2.DataSource = DT;
    BS3.DataSource = DT;

    // now we set them to be the DatSource of the DGVs:
    DGV1.DataSource = BS1;
    DGV2.DataSource = BS2;
    DGV3.DataSource = BS3;

    // now we can set the record pointers separately:
    BS1.Position = 3;        
    BS2.Position = 0;        
    BS3.Position = BS3.Count - 1;   

    // or set filters:
    BS2.Filter = "someCondition";  

    // or set sorts:
    BS3.Filter = "someSort";
```

Comment: @ TaW 
Thanks very much. One question though what if i have 2 more DGV how do i set their position?

Can i do like this:

 `BS4.Position = 2
  BS5.Position = 1`
without the count-1  ?

Comment: Yes, you can create any number of `BindingSources` and control each in any way you need..Just make them the `DataSources` of the other DGVs and should be good. The `BS3.Position = BS3.Count - 1;` was just an example of how you can show the __last__ record `(count - 1)`

Comment: thnx very much. I didn't know that with the `BindingSources`. Wish u a nice eve & easter

Comment: Gleichfalls! - BTW: `BindingSource` is easy to miss because you __seemingly__  get all its functionailty from `DataTable`alone as well. But in reality each `DataTable`  creates one `BindingSource` for its internal use; but __one__ only takes one so far..